# Find words between comma and list of keywords RegEx

Tags: regex, compilation, keyword

I have a large text. I would like to find the address of the owner. My input is something like...

> INPUT: (...) seiscientos catorce guión ocho, domiciliado en calle
>   Santillana número trescientos sesenta y nueve, Valle Lo Campino,
>   comuna de Quilicura, Región Metropolitana, constituyeron una sociedad
>   por acciones (...)

```
keywords_cap = ['DOMICILIO:', 'Domicilio:', 'Domicilio', 'DOMICILIO', 'domiciliado en', 'domiciliada en',
                                        'Domiciliado en', 'Domiciliada en']
keywords_cap = map(re.escape, keywords_cap)
keywords_cap.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
obj = re.compile(r'\b(?:{})\s*(.*?)\.'.format('|'.join(keywords_cap)))
obj2 = obj.search(mensaje)
if obj2:
   company_name = obj2.group(1)
else:
   company_name = "None"
```

> OUTPUT: calle Santillana número trescientos sesenta y nueve

Something it is wrong, because I would like to extract the text between one word of keywords and the next comma (,) or the next point (.).

But the extraction is being since this list of Keywords to only the next point (.).

Can someone help me with this foolishness?

Comment: If you want to get the text before the comma, why use a dot? Replace `(.*?)\.` with `([^,]*)`

Comment: Sorry, I would like to say to the next comma or next point. Do you know?

Comment: Then use `([^,.]*)`, try `obj = re.compile(r'\b(?:{})\s*([^.,]*)'.format('|'.join(keywords_cap)))`

Comment: Of course... thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(.*?)\.` pattern matches any chars other than line break chars, as few as possible before the leftmost `.` char. It can be "converted" to `([^.]*)`, a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) pattern that matches 0 or more chars other than `.` (note that the only difference from the original pattern is that negated character classes also match linebreaks, which is a good feature in this case).

The solution will be to just add `,` into the character class:

```
obj = re.compile(r'\b(?:{})\s*([^.,]*)'.format('|'.join(keywords_cap))) 
                              ^^^^^^^^
```

The regex will look like

```
\b(?:DOMICILIO:|Domicilio:|Domicilio|DOMICILIO|domiciliado en|domiciliada en|Domiciliado en|Domiciliada en)\s*([^.,]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z9KQN6/1).

Comment: Sorry for the past answer, I still do not understand this forum well.

Comment: @AnnaCastan It is not a forum, it is a Quesion&Answer site. Please note that you should also add the corresponding language tag to the question, it will bring more visitors to your question.